# Improve reCaptcha 2.0 solving automation script (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, recaptcha

I've written a python with selenium code to solve [new behaviour captcha](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/). But something is lacking as to fully imitate user behaviour: the code works to locate and click on a captcha, yet after that google sets up additional pictures check [image]

which is not easy to automate. How to improve the code to solve captcha immediately without pictures check (letting google no hint of robot presence)?

### Python code

```
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# to imitate hovering 
def hover(element):  
    hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hov.perform()
# optional: adding www.hola.org proxy profile to FF (extention is installed on FF, Win 8) 
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
hola_file = '/Users/Igor/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/7kcqxxyd.default-1429005850374/extensions/hola/hola_firefox_ext_1.9.354_www.xpi'
ffprofile.add_extension(hola_file) 
# end of the optional part

driver = webdriver.Firefox(ffprofile) 
url='http://tarex.ru/testdir/recaptcha/recaptcha.php'

# open new tab, also optional 
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
driver.get(url)

recaptchaFrame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME ,'iframe'))
        )
frameName = recaptchaFrame.get_attribute('name')

# move the driver to the iFrame... 
driver.switch_to_frame(frameName)

# *************  locate CheckBox  **************
CheckBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,"recaptcha-anchor"))
        )

# *************  hover CheckBox  ***************
rand=uniform(1.0, 1.5)
print('\n\r explicit wait for ', rand , ' seconds...')
sleep(rand) 
hover(CheckBox)

# *************  click CheckBox  ***************
rand=uniform(0.5, 0.7)
print('\n\r explicit wait for ', rand , 'seconds...')
sleep(rand)
# making click on CheckBox... 
clickReturn= CheckBox.click()
print('\n\r after click on CheckBox... \n\r CheckBox click result: ' , clickReturn)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't do that, I think the image obstacle is used when too many requests are done from the same IP anyway, so you can't bypass it, what you can do is use proxies

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')

# find iframe
captcha_iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'
        )
    )
)

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(captcha_iframe).click().perform()

# click im not robot
captcha_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.ID, 'g-recaptcha-response'
        )
    )
)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", captcha_box)
```

Comment: Does it work? How stable is it (how many times it may successfully solve before google sets image puzzle)?

Comment: I strongly recommend to run it first... It's hard to say about its stability. Very often It depends on User-Agent and proxies. What is more, your requests cannot be so often - using there longer delays may help.

Comment: What is going on with the code? Please explain each line.